# C - Going over char limit - standard rules

Tags: c, size, limit, standards

This code:

```
signed char a = 128;
a++;
printf("%d", a);
```

Prints value of '-127'.
I understand why that is, basically the value "resets" when it reaches the limit and goes from there, but I have trouble finding out if that is specified in standard, or it's just a random action my compiler does?

Comment: Enable and don't igonre compiler warnings! `128` is most likely already an invalid value for a `signed char` on your platform.

Comment: @Olaf There was no warning...

Comment: Please read my answer where I eleaborate more than a comment can. You should read my comment **carefully** again, too. Concentrate on the meaning of the first word if you did not get a warning by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the most common platforms with 8 bit `char` types and 2's complement (x86, ARM, MIPS, PPC, MSP430, etc.), the following happens:

- `128` is too large for a `signed char`. It is converted in an **implementation defined** way to a `signed char`. Typically it is simply truncated and bit-copied (1:1). In 2's complement, `0b1000000` is the 2's complement representation of decimal -128 in a `signed char`.
- The following addition is basic maths: `-128 + 1 -> -127`

On other platforms, the result varies, but most likely they just use the lower bits of the `int` constant `128`.

To detect such flaws (but not all), enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them. gcc will report a truncation warning (`-Wconversion`) for the initialiser.

Comment: Now you completely confused me.
I am not planing to use this in a real program, rather I am wondering because it might be a question in my exam. I do not need "probable" output, I just need to know if it's specified by a standard or random action of compiler. I even wrote this with asumption that char is 1 byte for sake of simplicity.

Comment: @NerminaAvdić: `implementation defined` **is** a term of the standard, look it up! It means it is defined by the **implementation**. That means your implementation has to define how it handles such cases. I gave information how this is handle on common implemntations/platforms; For obvious reasons I cannot cover all. Anyway, it is clear that it is **no** "random action of the compiler" (if such a thing could even exist in a software).

Comment: @NerminaAvdić: A `char` type **is always one byte**. That's how it is defined! A byte is not guaranteed to have 8 bits, though! Addituionally the encoding of negative values is not guaranteed to be 2's complement. My answer is as clear as your question allows. If you are on a different platform than the listed, you should clarify this **in the question** and provide all information required for a final answer. Otherwise I gave enough information for you to find out yourself.

Comment: So, in conclusion, (if running on a 32-bit machine where 1 byte is 8 bits) if value above 127 is implemented, signed char will consider it a second complement and print out it's value accordingly? Or there are some other implementation rules I'm missing here?

Comment: @NerminaAvdić: I did not say it is for all 32 bit platforms (and to be clear: 32 bit platform does not automatically imply 8 bits/byte; there can 32 bit platforms with only 32 bit accesses). But most likely (for gcc, I'm sure on the platforms mentioned). As I wrote: you have to check your compiler's documentation. And it is "two's complement" (hence the apostroph), not "second complement" - look it up! And take this seriously: **enable all relevant warnings**

Answer (score -2):

signed char is from -128 to 127.

no warning was there? = 128?

from -128 + 1 = -127, it is ok.

at run-time from 127 + 1 to -128 the compiler is not supposed to calculate there.